# rename randomly images in folder with R

Tags: r, image, file, directory, rename

I have a folder with 100,000 images. I would like to rename each file (image_.jpg) from 1 to 100,000 but randomly.

I use the following lines to rename but I do not know how to randomize the files.

```
library(jpeg)
setwd("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/R/New dataset/")
folder <- "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/R/New dataset 64"
jpeg <- list.files(folder)
total <- as.numeric(length(jpeg))
first <- 1
max <- first + total -1
file.rename(jpeg, paste0("image_", first:max, ".jpg"))
```

Comment: Do you really want to _rename_ the files? Maybe just assigning a random ID to each file might be a better idea, depending on what you want to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way -

```
file.rename(jpeg, paste0("image_", sample(length(jpeg)), ".jpg"))
```

**Note -**

You may want to use `jpeg <- list.files(folder, pattern = ".jpg")` or some other pattern if one exists to be safe if there are other files in the folder.